# Chopped placeholders on mobile safari

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a problem with placeholders on mobile safari. I've tested it on iOS 10 and 11 and so far I couldn't find any solution. Here are the screenshots from iOS Safari and Firefox/Chrome (desktop devtools, but looks the same on Android):

[image: Screenshot from iOS Safari and mobile Firefox/Chrome]

Here are the placeholder styles that I'm using right now:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #555555;
  text-indent: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 !important;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

And inputs:

```
.form__input {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-indent: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  padding: 1rem !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Same styles goes for "::-moz-placeholder", ":-ms-input-placeholder" and ":-moz-placeholder". i've also tries with "padding: 0 !important", different text-indent. On inputs I've tried with fixed height with 0 padding, but also no luck.

What is going on here? In the webkit placeholder specs that I've found there is literally nothing that should cause this. Have anyone had similar problem and found any solution?

Comment: try font-size:16px for your inputs on mobile

Comment: @AbbasNabilou - not working. Could use an explanation why that would work rhough.

Comment: inputs on mobiles had issues like auto zooming when they have values in em or etc... font-size:16px could fix it. try working around line-height...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, changing font-size didn't help, but adding "line-height: normal" to inputs and text-area fixed the issue on iOS Safari. I've checked it also on other browsers and it look fine too. Right now the styles are:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder (and other vendor specific selectors)
  color: #555555;
  text-indent: 1rem;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

And:

```
.form__input {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-indent: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: Before entering the question I already knew what was going to get asked and was ready to provide the same answer. Bonus tip: vertical padding is also useless in `input` elements - `height` takes care of everything.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, may be useful someday :)

Comment: also having a reset CSS can be beneficial as browsers behave differently :)

Comment: Yeah, even though I have normalize.css always included in all of my projects, Safari seems to sometimes have some weird behaviour regardless ;p

Answer (score 0):

Force font-size:

`.form__input {
  font-size: 13px;
}`